# How to create a carousel in HTML with previous/next images visible on left/right sides?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering how to create a slider with images, **so that previous and next ones are visible on the left/right edges, while active one is always centered**.
I can show previous or next slides using margin-left/margin-right with negative values, but when I scroll to the next one, **it won't be centered because of this margin.**

Should I apply and remove negative margins with js script? How to do so?

I show my idea with two simple screenshots that show what happens scrolling to the right, from 1st slide to 2nd one:

[image: 1st slide active]

[image: 2nd slide active]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  centerMode: true,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
});

$('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', 1);
```

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 450px;
}

.slider .slick-slide {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
}

.slider .slick-slide .inner {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  min-height: 550px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      SLIDE 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      SLIDE 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      SLIDE 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First hide the horizontal overflow on the parent container.

Then I guess you could do something like this

```
<div class="container-item" style="--i: 0"></div>
<div class="container-item" style="--i: 1"></div>
<div class="container-item" style="--i: 2"></div>


.container-item{
    --active: 0
    transform: translateX(calc((var(--i) - var(--active))* width ))
} 

//width refers to the width of the current element which has to be set by you or you may use javascript to find that
```

and use Javascript to change the value of --active when the carousel arrows are clicked.

The syntax that I used within the calc function might not be valid so you'll have to tweak that around a bit.